# evaluation of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently going through analysis. While learning ODE's I found some step I can't understand.

$\dfrac{dp(x)}{p(x)}=\dfrac{d x}{1+x} \Rightarrow \ln p(x)=\ln(x+1)+\ln C$

Comment: I don't know why the right hand side contains $+ \ln C$, I think it should be $+C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was done by integrating both sides.